# Ran _git rm --cached *.pyc and now No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, git

I kept getting merge conflicts when trying to git pull from github to my production server and a lot of them had to do with the .pyc files.

So on my local machine, I ran

```
_git rm --cached *.pyc
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin dev
```

Since I had `*.pyc` in my `.gitignore` but hadn't committed properly.

Anyways, when I go to `git pull` on my production server, everything is pulled fine no merge conflicts.

But then I kept getting server errors on my site when trying to access the admin panel and this is the error

```
 File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Obviously I have a virtual env working and this must be because the `__pycache__` files were removed with the latest commit.

Can anyone help me? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: hi, how do you initialize the virtual environment? and how you run the django?

Comment: Hi @BearBrown long time no see. I was inside the wrong virtualenv. Silly mistake.

Comment: sometimes it's happens)

Answer (score 1):

I was in the wrong `virtalenv`...I had set up the project while I was still learning so had a few `virtualenvs`

I have since overhauled the old project and created a new clean VPM with only one.